# Identity 3.0 - How to use AspNetUsers ID as Foreign Key in a Tiered Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

**Intention:**

A **Subscriptions** database table which contains a **UserId** column, which has a foreign key relationship to the **Id** column of the **AspNetUsers** table.

**Project Setup *(in order of their reference hierarchy)*:**

- Web Layer (Contains ApplicationDbContext and ApplicationUser class)
- DTO Layer
- Data Access Layer (Contains EFDbContext)

Project is **Code-First** configuration.

**Database Setup:**

Both ApplicationDbContext and EFDbContext reference the *same database*.

- ApplicationDbContext: References all Identity entities
- EFDbContext: References my Subscriptions entity (among others)

**Question:**

Given that my EFDbContext is located in my data layer, **which does not contain any references to Identity 3.0**, is it possible to create a Foreign Key constraint between AspNetUsers and Subscriptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a Foreign Key constraint between AspNetUsers and Subscriptions?

Sure it is. It's a common thing you will run into when you're crossing boundaries like that.

Instead of having EF create the relationships you need to

- create a new empty migration
- add the code to define the foreign key to the up method
- add the code to undo the foreign key in the down method
- run the migration on the database

The migration will look something like:

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Table_PrincipalTable_TableId",
            table: "Table",
            column: "PrincipalTableId",
            principalTable: "PrincipalTable",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade)
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Table_PrincipalTable_TableId",
            table: "Table");
    }
```

Comment: Wonderful, I never thought of adding the FK in the migration directly. Always relied on EF. Works like a charm and I added my solution to the question. Thanks!